# string to integer type in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

i make a textbox,enter some data, store it into string format,there are some values as numbers,can i change these string numbers into integer format
the problrm is for visual c++ in visual studio in the windows form

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can use the atoi() method, check [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/).

Comment: can u give the exact coding for that i am unable to get it

Comment: There is a example when you follow the link. Can't help more at the moment... But must be something like: int i = atoi(yourString);

Comment: that was a c ++  code...its not working in visual studio windows forms

Comment: So you are implementing in .NET? If so first of all your tag is obviously not precise enough as it just says "visual-c++". If you are implementing C# the code would be int i = Int32.Parse(yourString); C++-CLI would be int i = Int32::Parse(yourString);